# Problems executing jupyter notebook script from cmd in windows

Tags: python, cmd, jupyter-notebook

First I added the 2 directory paths where I installed Anaconda3 in the `Path` system variable because I was getting this error:

> 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

i.e. 1. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

2. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts

However, I still cannot execute the script. I get a bunch of Tracebacks and the error at the end:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I am not sure where my script file needs to be but I tried 2 directories. First the initial directory where jupyter creates it and next I moved it inside the `\Anaconda3\Scripts` folder but both to no avail. I am also getting the same error if I try to run jupyter from cmd.

Comment: did you try running it from anaconda prompt?

Comment: That is just opening the jupyter file in the browser. I would like to execute it like you would normally do  with a python file: python test.py arg1 arg2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython notebooks are stored in `.ipynb` formats. While python files are of `.py` format. This being said, you'll have to convert the notebook to a python file.

cd into the directory your notebook exists and type the following in your command prompt

`$ jupyter nbconvert --to script [NOTEBOOK_NAME].ipynb`

A `.py` file with the same name should now be there in the same directory.

You can find other export options available, and the examples mentioned in their [docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/nbconvert.html)